# about K8s pod memory limit

Tags: kubernetes

If a Node has 60G,the application process used 20G ,the pace Cache used 10G

If pod memory request and memory limit is 32G,when the pod memory reached 32G,before k8s kill the pod , any memory recycle,eg page Cache recycle ?

Comment: The normal Linux kernel memory-management rules still apply.  In the scenario you describe, the node isn't under particular memory pressure, but regardless, the kernel still has to balance process memory space, disk cache, and so on, the same way it would if the node weren't running Kubernetes.

Answer (score 3):

Kubernetes always check two factors available resources and used resources and the scheduler calculate which node will be able to run your application.

So the request and the limit should be work of course when you have available resources (ram,cpu).

The Limit parameter work specially for application that maybe use a lot of resources to kill the pod when he attend the limit .